# How I can add the predict data and the actual data in the same graph with ChartJS?

Tags: charts, chart.js, predict

I want to adda the predict data and the actual data in real time in the same graph to get something like that:
[image]

my code is like that:

```
 xArr.push(jsonRes[i].timestamp)
    yArr.push(jsonRes[i].deplacement)
    yMax.push(3)
    yMin.push(-3)
    yPredict.push()
    // draw chart
    let canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: xArr,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Déplacement cumulé de la chaine inclinométrique (mm)', // Name the series
          data: yArr, // Specify the data values array
          fill: false,
          borderColor: '#2196f3', // Add custom color border (Line)
          backgroundColor: '#2196f3', // Add custom color background (Points and Fill)
          borderWidth: 1 // Specify bar border width
        }, {
          label: 'Déplacement max toléré', // Name the series
          data: yMax, // Specify the data values array
          fill: true,
          borderColor: '#b30000'
        }, {
          label: 'Déplacement min toléré', // Name the series
          data: yMin, // Specify the data values array
          fill: true,
          borderColor: '#b30000'
        }, {
          label: 'ML', // Name the series
          data: yPredict, // Specify the data values array
          fill: true,
          borderColor: '#b30000'
        }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true, // Instruct chart js to respond nicely.
        maintainAspectRatio: false, // Add to prevent default behaviour of full-width/height 
      }
    });
```

I want to get an unique graph where I will have a part of actuel data in real time and the next part of predict data. All these datas come from a database as timeseries.

Answer (score 1):

you can use plugin and chagne the chartLineStlyle from where you want to dashed.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html

Use plugin available hook

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
plugins: [{
    beforeInit: function(chart, options) {
        //..
    }
}] });
```